# Internet access problems on subnet

Tags: configuration, router, subnet, pfsense, internet

Hello Server Fault friends!

I have a question that I believe should be easy to answer for someone who really gets how a typical subnet should be configured with a router such as PFSense.

**My Problem: I am not able to access the Internet from one of my subnets (the LAB)... my network looks like this**

[image]

Here is some information I hope could help troubleshoot the problem.

### Tracert with Network Name

On my HOME NETWORK machines things look good
[image]

From my LAB NETWORK, it goes only as far as the pfSense WAN interface
[image]

### pfSense Configuration

Here is one of the interface configuration pages (HOME)
[image]

...and here is the other interface (LAB)
[image]

Here is the IPv4 routing table
[image]

### Communication from my pfSense to the Internet (TELCO) Router

One thing I discovered while troubleshooting that I think gets closer to the gist of the problem is the fact that pfSense can PING the Internet (TELCO) Router when using the HOME interface but not when using the LAB interface. Is as if the Internet Router didn't want to talk to my LAB network.

[image]

### Gateways Configuration

Here is a print-screen of my Gateways configuration on pfSense, to address the question of whether I had 192.168.100.254 configured as my Default Gateway. I tried with and without this entry but nothing seems to work
[image]

I can provide more configuration screens if needed. pfSense has so many configuration pages that I honestly don't know exactly where to start... is a bit overwhelming.

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 1):

You don't have a default route set.

In short you'll have to add your up stream as [default gateway](https://docs.netgate.com/pfsense/en/latest/routing/gateways.html), and possibly turn on masquerading as well.

Given that you find pfsense overwhelming, it's probably a good idea to perform a clean install, and select the upstream interface as WAN, and downstream as LAN. That way you'll have a working, sensible, starting point from which you can learn.

Comment: Hi vidarlo

I do have 192.168.100.254 as the default gateway in the System / Routing / Gateways. I'm adding a print-screen on my original post of that page

Comment: You may have it there, but you have no `0.0.0.0`  route listed under IPv4 routes.

Answer (score 0):

Does your PFSense router actually have IP forwarding enabled?
Does it allow traffic between its two connected networks?
Does it perform any sort of NAT?
Do all the *other* routers involved know where they should send packets addressed to the networks on the other sides to the router itself?

Comment: If by IP forwarding you mean Port Forwarding (Firewall / NAT / Port Forwarding) the answer is: NO

Does it allow traffic between its two connected networks? YES, actually boxes in 192.168.100.x can ping all the 192.168.101.x and viceversa (I even start RDP sessions on my LAB machines from my HOME machines with no problem) the only problem seems to be the gateway that sends the traffic to Internet (192.168.100.254 in my diagram). That particular box is only seen by the 192.168.100.x boxes (HOME) but not by the 192.168.101.x boxes (LAB)
Does it perform any sort of NAT? NO

Comment: Do all the other routers involved know where they should send packets addressed to the networks on the other side of the router? The only problem again is that 192.168.100.254 (Default Gateway) router. From that router I cannot ping nor tracert any boxes on 192.168.101.x

Answer (score 0):

After a lot of investigation I finally ended up achieving internet connectivity on my LAB!

I watched this presentation...
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=bU_OYWzjJms

And at about 1 hour into the video there is a demo where the upstream (default) gateway connectivity is being troubleshoot. As the scenario looked pretty much like mine, I continued watching and noticed that the person showing the demo goes to the wan interface "Upstream gateway" combo box and adds the Default Gateway.

I thought by now that my setting would have this gateway there (as I entered as the "Default Gateway" on System / Routing / Gateways) but entering my gateway there is not the same as entering it in the WAN interface configuration.

[image]

I still don't understand what the differences are of entering my default gateway in the WAN interface configuration (where I was missing it) vs. the System / Routing / Gateways, but missing that crucial configuration was the one and only thing solving the problem.

As a consequence of adding this setting, I also see that new Automatic Rules were added in the Firewall / NAT / Outbound

[image]

I hope all these information in my original post and the resolution can eventually help someone to troubleshoot a similar future problem!

Thanks everybody!